# R function for doing all pairwise comparisons for two vectors

Tags: r

I am guessing that this exists somewhere in R already, so maybe you could point me to it.

I have two numerical vectors, A and B.

```
A <- c(1,2,3)
B <- c(2,3,4)
```

I am looking for a function which does something like doing each possible comparison between A and B, and returning a vector of the T/F of those comparisons.

So in this case, it would compare: 1>2 then 1>3 then 1>4 then 2,2 then 2>3 then 2>4 then 3>2 then 3>4 and return:

```
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

It would be fine if it returned the differences, as that could be easily converted.

Does a function like this already exist?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is off topic for CV, but on topic for stackoverflow. If you flag it a moderator will move it there for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`outer` is probably the function you want. However, it returns a matrix, so we need to get a vector. Here's one way of many:

```
 a <- 1:3
 b <- 2:4
 as.vector(outer(a,b,">"))
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

(that's not the order you specified though; it is, however, a consistent order)

Also:

```
 as.vector(t(outer(a,b,">")))
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Now for differences:

```
> as.vector(outer(a,b,"-"))
[1] -1  0  1 -2 -1  0 -3 -2 -1
```

I find that `outer` is very useful. I use it regularly.

Comment: Instead of using `c` for its side effect, you will have more readable code if you use `as.vector`.

Comment: I debated with myself which would be better (and noted that there were other ways) - while I agree it's more readable, from what I've seen, people tend to use `c` much more, and I figured that it might be better understood for that reason. I don't see `as.vector` much by comparison. I'll change it.